# Passing a text file in a Python as a function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a data science beginner tutorial and just copied the code. But I am unable to get rid of the "invalid syntax" error in my function.

Already tried to change it into self but then I get an error when I try to "call" the function.

```
class DataAlgorithmus:
    def readDataSet("/Users/leo/Desktop/DS_Code/Example.txt"):

        fr = open("/Users/leonard/Desktop/DS_Code/Example.txt")  
        numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())  
        returnMat = numpy.zeros((numberOfLines-1, 3))
        classLabelVector = []
        classColorVector = []
        fr = open("/Users/leonard/Desktop/DS_Code/Example.txt") 
        index = 0

        for line in fr.readlines(): 
            if index != 0:         
                line = line.strip()
                listFromLine = line.split('\t')
                returnMat[index-1, :] = listFromLine[1:4]

                classLabel = listFromLine[4]
                if classLabel == "Buero":
                    color = 'yellow'
                else:
                    color = 'blue'

                classLabelVector.append(classLabel)
                classColorVector.append(color)
            index += 1

        return returnMat, classLabelVector, classColorVector

    dataSet, classLabelVector, classColorVector = readDataSet("/Users/leonard/Desktop/DS_Code/Example.txt")
```

It says that this line: 
`def readDataSet("/Users/leo/Desktop/DS_Code/Example.txt"):`

has the following error:
`invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 3) pylint(syntax-error) [3,1]`

Comment: You're confusing *values* and *parameters*. You can't hard-code a parameter as a value like that; you need to provide a default value for the parameter or call the method with a value.

Comment: The `def` statement *defines* a function/method.  The statement should list local variable names for the arguments passed to the function when you call it.  Not an actual value (you're not calling the function here, only defining it).  Have a closer look at your Python tutorial's guide to how to define functions and classes.

Comment: For example in this case write `def readDataSet(self, filename)` and everywhere in the method definition replace the actual filename with the variable `filename`.  You already pass in an actual filename later when you call it.

Comment: Here also you're defining a *method* on a class.  Not a plain function.  Did you intend to create a class?  If not, you don't need it.  In Python you can define just a bare function that does not belong to a class.  It seems to me that's probably what you wanted to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @jonrsharpe & @Iguananaut I edited my code and it works now!

```
def readDataSet(self, filename):

    fr = open(filename)  
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())  
    returnMat = numpy.zeros((numberOfLines-1, 3))
    classLabelVector = []
    classColorVector = []
    fr = open(filename) 
    index = 0

    for line in fr.readlines(): 
    if index != 0:         
            line = line.strip()
            listFromLine = line.split('\t')
            returnMat[index-1, :] = listFromLine[1:4]

            classLabel = listFromLine[4]
            if classLabel == "Buero":
                color = 'yellow'
            else:
                color = 'blue'

            classLabelVector.append(classLabel)
            classColorVector.append(color)
        index += 1

    return returnMat, classLabelVector, classColorVector

dataSet, classLabelVector, classColorVector = readDataSet("/Users/leonard/Desktop/DS_Code/Example.txt")
```